# Angular-ui bootstrap modal without creating new controller

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-controller

plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/85Wl5W If I use the $modalInstance on the same controller(modalController.js), without being in a modal, angular gets frozen.

I just want to simplify my life using angularjs with the angular-ui bootstrap modal service. I want to use the same controller on a separate file, but on a modal as well. That is, I want them to do the same task. Is there any proper way to do it?

E.g. modal.html, modalController.js. I want to show these on a modal window, but on my application as well without a modal. The issue is that if I use the same controller I can't inject the $modalInstance, as it's undefined if there's no modal.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: You can achieve that by having return value of modal.open in a Var and using that variable fir closing the modal

Comment: Some code examples (a Plunkr) would be helpful

Comment: I just added a plunk, I hope you understand now what I mean.

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/23780950/605586 see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34531464/605586

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found a clean solution yet, the best workaround I found, to avoid writing the same code twice was to extend the modal controller like this:

```
$.extend(this, $controller('NormalCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));
```

full controller:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$controller', '$modalInstance', 
function ($scope, $controller, $modalInstance) {
    //with this line here:
    // Initialize the super class and extend it.
    $.extend(this, $controller('NormalCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));

    // Opens a search result
    $scope.openResult = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selectedRow);
    };

    // Called when the cancel button is pressed
    $scope.back = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

}]);
```

That way, I can re-use the same code, without having to rewrite it all over again and I can override the functions that I want to do smth different to the original controller.

Hope I helped some people out there,

Alex

Answer (score 30):

It was possible in older version of UI-Bootstrap 0.10.0 .Even latest version,it works for me

### index.html

```
<!-- if you are using Bower -->    
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js">
</script>

<!-- modal -->
<!-- look at 'type' and 'id' values -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTestModal.tmpl.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Modal Header</h3>
    </div>   

    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal Body</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()" data-dismiss="modal">Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something
        </button>
    </div> 
</script>
```

### modalDemoController.js

```
$scope.openModal=function(){
    $scope.modalInstance=$modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myTestModal.tmpl.html',
        scope:$scope
    });
}

$scope.close=function(){
    $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();//$scope.modalInstance.close() also works I think
};

$scope.doSomething=function(){
    //any actions to take place
    console.log("Do Something");
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution as well! If _if($scope.modalInstance)_ works then it could be used to avoid creating 2 controllers.

Comment: A side note: if `modalInstance` is not something to reference from a view (HTML) then I would not store that into `$scope`. I think it would be better to keep that as a controller (private) *field*.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this with version before 0.12.0, but you can use $close(result) and $dismiss(reason) directly in the modal markup for the ng-click targets, instead of passing the targets on the modalInstance. Then you can act on the promise returned from "modalInstance.result", as you would with a typical modal.

Comment: how to pass data from the main controller to the modal with this approach

Comment: inheriting the parent scope in directive

`scope:$scope`

Comment: @SpencerKormos using `$close()` was just the solution I needed, thanks.

Comment: Works fine with latest bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Just write a function instead of creating new file:

```
 $scope.yourModal= function (data) {
   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     template: '<div>Do you really want to hurt me? <div><button class="btn" ng-click="hurt(data)">Yes</button></div></div>',
     controller: function($scope, scope){
        $scope = scope;
     },
     resolve: {
         scope: function () {
            return $scope;
         }
     },
     size: 'sm'
   });  
 }

 $scope.hurt = function(data){
     console.log(data);
 }
```

Comment: Would love to hear why this got downvoted. What's wrong with this?