# Manually inject $modalInstance later into controller

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular UI bootstrap and want to re-use the controller used in a modal dialog in a view that is not a dialog.

I tried to manually get the $modalInstance later via

`$injector.get('$modalInstance')`, but this does not work ( `$injector.has('$modalInstance')` equals `false` )

It only works when I directly inject it via

```
angular.module('mymodule').controller('MyModalCtrl', function($modalInstance) {
  // do something with $modalInstance
});
```

Is there a way to re-use the controller-code or do I have to write two separate controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick to reuse the modal controller by passing the modalInstance through caller's $scope, so you won't have Unknown provider problem.

I answered it here:
[Passing modalInstance through $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25418480/1991818)