# Reuse Angular Controller for Modal and Non-Modal

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-bootstrap

How would I go about reusing an angular controller for the purposes of a modal as well as a non-modal? I have a new business requirement to have the same form that exists already in a modal (just the modal body) placed in a tab within a new page.

Currently I'm using `resolve` within my modal initialization to pass a variable to the modal's controller.

**Modal Initialization**

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    resolve: {
        foo: function() { return scope.fooFromScope; },
    }
});
```

**Existing Controller**

```
myApp.controller('hrpoConductReviewModalCtrl', ['$scope', 'foo', function($scope, foo) {
    ...
}]);
```

Currently not using `$uibModalInstance` within my modal.

Is there a way to initialize a controller from within another controller and pass the `foo` variable? There is an existing question that asks the same thing but the main answer focuses on using `scope` within the modal initialization rather than `resolve`.

---

Existing Question: 
[How to use the same controller for modal and non-modal form in Angular UI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780950/how-to-use-the-same-controller-for-modal-and-non-modal-form-in-angular-ui-bootst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using ui-router you can just use the resolve from ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('conductReview', {
        url: '/review',
        templateUrl: '/js/templates/review.html',
        controller: 'hrpoConductReviewModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
            foo: function() { return scope.fooFromScope; },
            $uibModalInstance: function () { return null; } // <- workaround if you want to use $uibModalInstance in your controller.
        }
    })
```

In case you are not using ui-router you should definitely check it out ;-)

Comment: I'm currently not using ui-router but have been thinking this is the path I need to take.

Comment: Thanks for `$uibModalInstance: function () { return null; }` workaround :) ... +1