# Angular bootstrap ui modal with same controller instead of new controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap ui modal box it says to give a new $modalInstance for new controller.I want to use the same controller where i have initialized the modal box.I searched but no success.I found this links but no success -

[How to use the same controller for modal and non-modal form in Angular UI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780950/how-to-use-the-same-controller-for-modal-and-non-modal-form-in-angular-ui-bootst)
[Angular-ui bootstrap modal without creating new controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756105/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-without-creating-new-controller)

```
app.controller('UserCtrl',['$scope','$filter','ngTableParams','$modal',function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams,$modal) {

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl', //Instead of this i want to use the same controller 'UserCtrl'
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
 };
};

  } ]);
```

So that i can call the save function on this same controller which is called on save click of modal box

Comment: show the code used to generate the error.

Comment: Why do you want to use the same controller?  The answer to that could help derive a solution.  For example, do you already have variables in scope that you'd like to access?  If so, you can use scope inheritance to access those variables.

Comment: I want to call a function savedata() which is on the click of save button of modalbox..but without using modal instance function doesn't get fire.

Comment: @user1844266 look at the example in docs and how `close()` in modal controler passes promise back to `result` in original controller

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It was possible in older version of UI-Bootstrap 0.10.0
[Download](https://www.versioneye.com/javascript/angular-ui:angular-bootstrap/0.10.0) Library.Even latest version,it works for me

### index.html

```
<!-- if you are using Bower -->    
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js">
</script>

<!-- button click opens modal-->
<button ng-click="openModal()">Button test</button>

<!-- modal -->
<!-- look at 'type' and 'id' values -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTestModal.tmpl.html">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Modal Header</h3>
   </div>   

   <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Modal Body</p>
   </div>
 
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()" data-dismiss="modal">Close
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something
      </button>
   </div> 
</script>
```

### modalDemoController.js

```
$scope.openModal=function(){
    $scope.modalInstance=$modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myTestModal.tmpl.html',
        scope:$scope
    });
}

$scope.close=function(){
    $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();//$scope.modalInstance.close() also works I think
};

$scope.doSomething=function(){
    //any actions to take place
    console.log("Do Something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I managed to fix it by removing the `controller` inside of the `$uibModal.open({])`